# Calling the right URI with ODATA using ODataClient with Expand

Tags: filter, odata, expand

I have two tables which are related to each other and I would like to perform some querying with filters on both tables (one for each)

I am using a controller in c# that looks like this :

```
   var list =
           await client.For("T_Project")
          .Filter("IsQuote eq false")
          .Expand("T_Ref_StatusProject")
          .Filter("Final eq false")
          .FindEntriesAsync();
```

Here is the URI that I get with this code :

```
http://localhost:12494/gp/T_Project?$filter=(IsQuote eq false) and (Final eq false)&$expand=T_Ref_StatusProject
```

However, I get an error saying bad request. I figure the one I want would look something like

```
http://localhost:12494/gp/T_Project?$filter=(IsQuote%20eq%20false)&$expand=T_Ref_StatusProject($filter=Final%20eq%20true)
```

The result is, however, exactly the same as if I didn't put any filter for the expand table.

So I have actually two question. How can I make it work in my c# code and what is the right URL syntax for it. I figure answering the first one will answer the second one.

My UI project (the one with the sample code) have Simple.OData.Client(5.0.0 alpha2) installed (which include Microsoft.Odata.Code (6.15.0)

My API have Microsoft.ASPNet.Odata V5.9.1 installed

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the ODATA documentation filtering on nested properties would look like this:

```
http://localhost:12494/gp/T_Project?$filter=(IsQuote eq false) and (T_Ref_StatusProject/any(d:d/Final eq false))
```

See QueryOptions 5.1.1.10.1 any, http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html, see also "Addressing Derived Types" in the document which describes the concept in general.

I cannot help you on the first part of your question, as I am not using the C# client. But maybe you can check if the `Filter()` method accepts a lambda expression, where you can specify an expression that directly corresponds to the expanded entity.